# Installing Windows 7 after Ubuntu: returning /home to root partition, editing MBR

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

There's nothing to be done, I need a Windows OS for work. The .iso should be ready, thanks to WinUSB.

I have two questions:

First, the HDD currently has four partitions:

- Ext4 / (boot)
- /linux-swap
- Ext4 /home
- /ntfs

Apparently Win7 requires 2 primary partitions, so I assume that I will have to fold /home back in to the root partition. How should I do this?

Second, to dual-boot, I understand that I will have to use a Live USB to edit the MBR. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 does not need two primary partitions. If you are partioning your disk within Windows 7 Installer, it will automatically create two primary partitions for Windows. But if you create your partition yourself, you can still install Windows 7.

So if you want to install Windows to your NTFS partition, just boot your computer up with your USB disk and choose the partition when installing.

The installer, however, will erase GRUB. If you want to use GRUB for dual-booting (which is a better choice than using Windows bootmgr), you need to re-install GRUB.

To re-install GRUB, you could have a look at this question: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)